# spresense Arduino IDE タイマー割込み

Tags: arduino, spresense

下記の使い方がわかりません。
サンプル例、ご教示頂けないでしょうか？

```
void attachTimerInterrupt(unsigned int (*isr)(void), unsigned int us);
```

Answer (score 2):

Spresense の Arduino ライブラリのヘッダファイルを見てみたら、以下のように定義されていました。

```
void attachTimerInterrupt(unsigned int (*isr)(void), unsigned int us);
// Parameter:
//   isr: the function to call when the timer interrupt occurs.
//        This function must return the next timer period [microseconds].
//        If this function returns 0, the timer stops and it behaves as oneshot timer.
//   us: microseconds.
//       The maximum value is about 26 seconds and if it exceeds, an error occurs.
// Note:
//   This can not be used at the same time with tone().
```

コールバック関数の戻り値の扱いが少し分かりにくいですが、以下のようなコードを書いてみたら、なんとなく動きました。

```
#define INTERVAL 100

static unsigned long counter = 0;

unsigned int callback_func() {
  Serial.print("callback_func called ");
  Serial.print(++counter);
  Serial.println(" times");
  return INTERVAL;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  attachTimerInterrupt(callback_func, INTERVAL);
}

void loop() {

}
```

以上、ご参考になれば。

Answer (score 0):

お疲れ様です。
あまりネット上にサンプルがころがっていない感じですね。
attachInterrupt
ならば、たくさんあるので、それを参考にして下さい。
おそらく、ISRとかお詳しくないんですよね。